# How to iterate rows in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have the following code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import csv


location = r'C:\Users\tmaina\Desktop\scf\output.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(location,sep='\s*,\s*',engine='python')
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['COUPON_NUMBER'] == 1:
        df.OND_ORIGIN = df.DEP_FROM 
        if  df.loc[i+1,'PLDATE'] == row['PLDATE'] & row['TICKET_NUMBER'] ==df.loc[i+1,'TICKET_NUMBER'] &row['COUPON_NUMBER'] == 2:
            df.OND_DEST = df.loc[i+1,'ARR_TO']
        else:
            df.OND_DEST = df.ARR_TO
    elif row['COUPON_NUMBER'] == 2 & row['TICKET_NUMBER'] ==df.loc[i-1,'TICKET_NUMBER'] & row['PLDATE'] ==df.loc[i-1,'PLDATE']:
        df.OND_ORIGIN==df.loc[i-1,'DEP_FROM']
        df.OND_DEST = df.ARR_TO
    elif row['COUPON_NUMBER'] == 3 & row['TICKET_NUMBER'] ==df.loc[i-1,'TICKET_NUMBER'] & row['PLDATE'] !=df.loc[i-1,'PLDATE']:
        df.OND_ORIGIN = df.DEP_FROM
        if  df.loc[i+1,'PLDATE'] == row['PLDATE'] & row['TICKET_NUMBER'] ==df.loc[i-1,'TICKET_NUMBER']:
            df.OND_DEST = df.loc[i+1,'ARR_TO']
        else:
            df.OND_DEST = df.ARR_TO
    elif row['COUPON_NUMBER'] == 4 & row['TICKET_NUMBER'] ==df.loc[i-1,'TICKET_NUMBER']& row['PLDATE'] ==df.loc[i-1,'PLDATE']:
        df.OND_ORIGIN = df.loc[i-1,'DEP_FROM']
        df.OND_DEST = df.ARR_TO

df.to_csv('out.csv', sep=',',index = False)
```

The output for the following columns is

```
COUPON_NUMBER TICKET_NUMBER DEP_FROM    ARR_TO  OND_ORIGIN  OND_DEST  PLDATE   STOPOVER
    1          1054737998    HRE             NBO    HRE     NBO       20170419  O
    2          1054737998    NBO             KGL    NBO     KGL       20170419  X   
    3          1054737998    KGL             NBO    KGL     NBO       20170519  O   
    4          1054737998    NBO             HRE    NBO     HRE       20170419  X
```

The desired output is

```
COUPON_NUMBER TICKET_NUMBER DEP_FROM    ARR_TO  OND_ORIGIN  OND_DEST  PLDATE   STOPOVER
    1          1054737998    HRE         NBO    HRE         KGL       20170419  O
    2          1054737998    NBO         KGL    HRE         KGL       20170419  X   
    3          1054737998    KGL         NBO    KGL         HRE       20170519  O   
    4          1054737998    NBO         HRE    KGL         HRE       20170419  X
```

The logic is that for a given `coupon_number` belonging to a specific ticket, we check the `pldate`, if more than one coupon is flown on the same month, the `ond_origin` and `ond_dest` should be equal. The `ond_dest` is determined by checking whether there was a stop over at a particular city. If there is one, the `arr_to` becomes the `ond_dest` and the `ond_origin` becomes the first `dep_from` where there was no stop over.

Comment: @Chris noted, Thank you for the correction

Comment: how is your raw output.csv file format raws ?

Comment: We need some sample input that will create your expected output.

Comment: @ScottBoston Find the input in the following link: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-YHr391t2TxNDNwZjFRektJTWs

Comment: @BeyhanGül find the raw csv in the link  https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-YHr391t2TxNDNwZjFRektJTWs

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with `groupby`, [`Grouper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Grouper.html) and [`transform`](http://pbpython.com/pandas_transform.html) instead of iterating over each row. To get the first and last of each group, you can use [this](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#taking-the-nth-row-of-each-group)

If `PLDATE` is a datetime colummn you could do something like this

```
df['OND_ORIGIN'] = df.groupby(['TICKET_NUMBER', pd.Grouper(key='PLDATE', freq='1M')])['DEP_FROM'].transform(first)   
df['OND_DEST'] = df.groupby(['TICKET_NUMBER', pd.Grouper(key='PLDATE', freq='1M')])['ARR_TO'].transform(last)
```

the `Grouper` is only needed when you want to group per month. If it is per date, you can just do `df.groupby(['TICKET_NUMBER', 'PLDATE', freq='1M'])`

Comment: the PLDATE is not a datetime column, the date is converted into an int

Comment: representing dates or id's as ints can lead to strange effects, especially when `NaN`'s or leading zeroes are involved, so better avoid this. In this case that can be done by `df['PLDATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['PLDATE'].astype(str), format='%Y%m%d)`

Comment: Noted, thank you for the advise, I have implemented the above however am getting a name error since 'first' has not been defined.

Comment: [`first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.first.html). An alternative is `lambda x: x[0]` or `lambda x: x.first()` (and `x[-1]` for the last item) as aggregating function